# Can I mimic global window object in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Edit** I solved my actual problem in a way where this was no longer an issue, so I no longer need a solution to this. The question can remain though.

In a nodejs project I am analyzing dependencies by requiring them. This causes problems when some modules were built for the browser and expect `window` or `document` to be available. so for example, when I do `require('some-module')` I can get this kind of error:

```
hasEventListeners = !!window.addEventListener,
                    ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Is there any way I can mimic the window to get this type of code to work? The properties on `window` does not need to work as the actual version, I just need `require('some-module')` to return a valid value.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can with cheerio or a tool like this, by executing the script in the cheerio environment this would work i think

Comment: You might be able to do this with the (large) jsdom library, although you'd normally check something like `dom.window` instead of `window` directly. (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: No, there is some workaround, which @Cat mentioned in the comment. But as NodeJS is intended to run JavaScript on a server and there is no window available on the server. You might need to set `dom.window` in `global.window` before you require any module using the window object. Still not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: I am not in control of the scripts that use `window` so I would need simply `window` to be accessible

Comment: Apparently the ECMAScript standard doesn't reserve the word `window`. So I guess you could say `let window = {}` and assign all your `dom.window` properties to that object using jsdom. Note that jsdom is not a browser and there are some browser functions that it doesn't provide (but which you could presumably write yourself or import from elsewhere if you need something jsdom doesn't have.) This is all a bit hacky, but as long as you remove any of this code before building for production, it might be fun -- or it might be more work than you planned on doing. Maybe some cleaner solution exists.

Comment: In cases where you are in control of the code that needs window, I usually put window into its own module, which can then hold an internal variable that can be exported, which is set to window when it exists in the global scope. ```export const window = window || {}```. This makes all code share an object, which will be window when running in the browser.